# How would I wire a glass stove top with white black and bare wire to 2 black and 1 white wire coming out of the wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, stove

How would I wire up a range stove top with 1 white, 1 black, and bare ground wire.... to a junction box having 2 black wires that are hot, and 1 white common wire coming out of the junction box??

[image]

KitchenAid 36 Inch Wide Built-In Electric Cooktop
Model: KCES556HBL

Comment: We're going to need more details. Wire colors don't get us very far. Is the circuit 240v? Is the device 240v? What's the model? What was there before? Please revise your post to help us help you.

Comment: I'm not seeing any white wires.  I see two blacks and one uninsulated.

Comment: Words say one thing. Picture says something totally different. Take an actual picture and upload it

Comment: What gauge are the wires coming out of the wall? Also, I take it the wires from the cooktop are contained in a flexible metal conduit?

Comment: the circled wires look like aluminum

Comment: The wire coated in white insulation is a white wire.  OP, aside from the black-red-white wires you mentioned, is there **also** a bare wire separate from the white one?

Comment: @jsotola I think OP is trying to say: I have 3 wires from the wall and 3 wires from the cooktop, here is a *similar* picture with three wires from the wall - pretend the aluminum is copper and pretend the bare wire is white, and pretend the red wire from the cooktop is actually white, and everything copper there too, so everything is different but kind of the same, at least in terms of "3 wires here and 3 wires there".

Comment: You can see why pictures of your _actual_ situation, instead of some picture randomly grabbed from the internet is vital to getting you a good, accurate and, most importantly, **safe** answer. Nobody's going to ID your house to rob you from a reasonably close up pic like the one you posted, but with _your_ wiring.

Comment: Yes, can you post a photo of your specific situation please?

Comment: Harper's diagram is wonderful, as always. But what it doesn't tell us is whether the wires are in metal conduit or not. My hunch is that they are - two blacks means conduit and the older stuff that we typically see is metal rather than PVC. But anything is possible **and a picture would tell us for sure**.